# Should I put AWS Elasticsearch domain in VPC when it's consumed by Lambda functions only

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using AWS Elasticsearch service to run a publicly available ES domain, which is called by Lambda functions deployed outside of any VPC. I've configured a resource policy attached to the ES domain to restrict access only to an IAM role that my Lambda functions assume. Given the policy and the fact that all requests to my domain need to be signed, is there any additional security benefit of placing the ES domain inside a VPC in my scenario?

I understand that inside a VPC my ES domain will not be even available from the Internet, which from security perspective is a benefit for sure. On the other hand, that will require to put all my Lambda functions inside the same VPC, which poses a lot of configuration and performance challenges that I'd love to avoid.

My understanding is as follows: if we consider DynamoDB, S3, SNS, SQS or other AWS serverless services secure, and they use the same IAM security model, I should also consider my ES configuration safe. Of course you can always misconfigure the domain and make it publicly available for everyone, but the same is true for S3 buckets, and it doesn't prevent people from keeping private files there.

Am I missing something? Do you see any security holes in my thought process which should convince me to put the ES domain inside a VPC despite all the challenges related to Lambda functions configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having your ElasticSearch cluster in the VPC you're reducing the risk of exposure of data by far more than relying just on the domain policy.

By doing this you will need to consider the following:

- You will need to add a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [NAT Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) to your VPC private subnet to allow internet connectivity for the Lambda.
- If you want to connect to AWS services without a NAT for your Lambda you will need to configure [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) for each service.

Elasticsearch Service also has support for authentication via [signed HTTP requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html).

There is a section on [Security in Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/security.html) within the AWS documentation that should provide additional input.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on "you're reducing the risk of exposure of data by far more than relying just on the domain policy." I understand that hiding ES or DB in private network reduces the surface attack, but S3 buckets for example can't be placed inside a VPC, and they use similar IAM based model of security which most people find secure enough. Does leaving ES outside of VPC poses more threats than using a private bucket, which still has a public endpoint? In both cases you'll get 403 when trying to access either ES or S3 without proper permissions.

Comment: By reducing exposure I mean that from a networking perspective, it is private. The resource policy will always be evaluated by software so by keeping the networking private it reduces the risk of accessibility is there is no public internet route in that might be able to bypass in the future (not to mention an accidental update to the resource policy making it public). Whilst services such as S3 or DynamoDB are in the public zone of AWS you can restrict all interactions to be across a VPC endpoint now to keep network transit internal :)